# Blocks of type "cloud" are not expected here for integrating with Terraform Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-cloud

I'm following this documentation in migrating the local state to be integrated with Terraform Cloud.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-migrate

It is fairly straightforward, I just need to copy this code:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"
  required_providers {
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.0.1"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    organization = "<ORG_NAME>"
    workspaces {
      name = "Example-Workspace"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that my code below has the same code with above

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    organization = "ORG"

    workspaces {
      name = "ORG_WORKSPACE"
    }
  }
}
```

But it is returning an error:

```
Blocks of type "cloud" are not expected here.
```

Some notes:

1. I put the code in a file called `providers.tf`.
2. I have done some other code and did a `terraform apply`, thus returning tfstate.
3. I did a login to Terraform Cloud using `terraform login` with my credentials.
4. When I try to terraform init, the error occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cloud` is only supported in TF 1.1.0, not any older version. From [docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cloud-migrate):

> Because the cloud block is not supported by older versions of Terraform, you **must use 1.1.0 or higher** in order to follow this tutorial.

You have to **upgrade** your TF 0.14 to the newest version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Appreciate it!
I am currently trying to upgrade the TF to 1.1.0, but always failed because of error `This configuration does not support Terraform version 1.0.11.`
As I try to research it, it seems the .terraform.lock.hcl file is blocking me in updating the version. Can I just delete it and run a `terraform init` again? Or maybe there is a better solution for this?

Comment: Nvm, I was having terraform cli version of 1.0.11, and just do a `sudo apt install terraform=1.1.3` did the job. Thanks a lot!